# No transparent background despite setting transparent to 'true.'

Tags: lazarus

Just started with Lazarus. Here's the problem: I placed a panel on a form and set the panel's color to `clRed`. I then placed a `TImage` on the panel. I loaded a bitmap (.bmp) image into the image component.

However, although the image appears as it should, the background is not transparent (i.e. red), despite my having checked the 'transparent' box for the relevant `TImage` in the object inspector.

So, what have I done wrong this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Transparent" in relation to bmp means: Replace a given color by the background. Usually this color is defined by the pixel in the left/bottom (or top?) corner of the image. Do you have the correct color at this point?

Usually there are less issues with transparency if a png image with true alpha channel is loaded into the TImage. For a test try the paw.png in the folder images\splash_source\ of the Lazarus installation - it is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone; much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the bmp imageformat has no alpha channel and no transparent color.
So the TImage is transparent but the loaded image does not support transparency. The white imagebackground is still shown as white because the program doesn't know that it is white background and not white foreground. Try using a image Format that supports alpha values and a edit your image file to contain full or semi transparent colors. I recommend .PNG file Format and maybe just try some transparent images from Google or use gimp or paint.net to create own ones.